# change a value based on a subset of another variable in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, piping

I have a data set that has muscle activity data from a group of athletes who have had an ACL reconstruction.  I want to reassign the limb side to indicate the ACLR limb and uninjured limb.  Looking at the dataset called EMG below, suppose John had a left ACLR and Bob a right ACLR.

```
athlete     limb     EMG_value
John        left         0.8
John        right        1.2
Bob         left         0.5
Bob         right        0.9
```

I would want the data set to look like this:

```
athlete     limb       EMG_value
John        ACLR         0.8
John        uninjured    1.2
Bob         uninjured    0.5
Bob         ACLR         0.9
```

My original plan was to subset the data by athlete, change the limb value, and then bind the data back into the original data set.

An excerpt from process this is as follows:

```
John = subset(EMG, athlete=="John")

John$side<- as.character(John$side)

John$side[John$side=="Left"]="ACLR"
John$side[John$side=="Right"]="Uninjured"
John$side = as.factor(John$side)

Bob = subset(EMG, athlete=="Bob")

Bob$side<- as.character(Bob$side)

Bob$side[Bob$side=="Left"]="Uninjured"
Bob$side[Bob$side=="Right"]="ACLR"
Bob$side = as.factor(Bob$side)

EMG2 = rbind(Bob, John)
```

I'm sure there is a way to do this more quickly using data piping in dplyr. I'm sure there is a way to replace the value of a variable based on a specified condition.

The logic would be: if athlete==Bob then replace Left with ACLR and replace Right with Uninjured.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BTW: your logic and example contradict: you say "Bob" and "Left" means "ACLR" but your example data disagrees. Nonetheless:

```
library(dplyr)
## generalizable so you can easily add other patients, etc
leftAthletes <- c('Bob')

mutate(acl, limb=ifelse(xor(athlete %in% leftAthletes, limb == 'left'),
                        'uninjured', 'ACLR'))
##   athlete      limb EMG_value
## 1    John uninjured       0.8
## 2    John      ACLR       1.2
## 3     Bob      ACLR       0.5
## 4     Bob uninjured       0.9
```

(Note the use of `xor` ... the check within the `ifelse` essentially says *"if in leftAthletes and right limb, or not in leftAthletes and left limb, then uninjured else ACLR"*.)

Comment: That worked great - I wasn't aware of  ifelse and xor.  That was a game changer for me.  Thank you, and thanks for pointing out the mistake in the last part of my question.  Great solution.

Comment: Caveat emptor: `ifelse` is not a perfect solution for everything, and has known performance issues. @hadley has [discussed some performance issues with `ifelse`](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Performance.html), but when speed is not a concern, I find it relatively "elegant" and very readable.